# How do I return a list of objects using interfaces?

Tags: delphi

I have 2 interfaces ..

```
IInterfaceA = interface
  .....
End;

IInterfaceB = interface
['{834D7063-AE8F-40BF-B1E7-E0806EB991C7}']
  Function getA (A: Integer): IInterfaceA;
  Function getList: TList <IInterfaceA>;
End;

TClassA = class (TInterfacedObject, IInterfaceA)
  ....
End

TClassB = class (TInterfacedObject, IInterfaceB)
  Function getA (A: Integer): IInterfaceA;
  Function getList: TList <IInterfaceA>;
End;

// It works
Function TClassB.getA (A: Integer): IInterfaceA;
Begin
  Result: = Manager.Find <TClassA> .Add (Linq.Eq ('fieldxxx', A.ToString).) UniqueResult;
End;
```

The following does not work and produces this error:

> E2010 Incompatible types:
>   `'System.Generics.Collections.TList <IInterfaceA>'` and 
>   `'System.Generics.Collections.TObjectList <TClassB>'`

```
Function TClassB.getList: TList <IInterfaceA>;
Begin
  // The TClassA class implements the interface IInterfaceA

  Result: = Manager.Find <TClassA> .List;
End;
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: We can't see enough code. Can't we have a MCVE. The error message seems clear to me. Do you understand what it says.

Comment: I don't see sufficient code either. What type does `Manager.Find` return?

Comment: The error message tells us what the types are. The error message is really extremely clear. Sometimes people don't read them.

Comment: @David Well my comment was meant to be a rhetorical question :-)

Comment: This works, really?: `Result: = Manager.Find <TClassA> .Add (Linq.Eq ('fieldxxx', A.ToString).) UniqueResult;` That is weird, because it looks like a syntax error to me. So this is either not your exact code and then we don't know if the rest is exact and what is an error and what is simply a typo. It is impossible to tell what is going on. We don't know what `Manager` does, what `Find` does and what kind of `List` is returned. But the error message suggests it is not what you expect.

Answer (score 4):

It is obvious from the error message what the problem is.  `Manager.Find<TClassA>.List` is returning a `TObjectList<TClassB>` (why `TClassB` and not `TClassA`?), which is not the same type as `TList<IInterfaceA>`, so it cannot be returned as-is.

To make the code *compile*, you would need something more like this:

```
Function TClassB.getList: TList<IInterfaceA>;
var
  Obj: TClassA;
begin
  // The TClassA class implements the interface IInterfaceA
  Result := TList<IInterfaceA>.Create;
  try
    for Obj in Manager.Find<TClassA>.List do
      Result.Add(Obj as IInterfaceA);
  except
    Result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

However, this introduces two problems:

1. memory management of the `Result`.  Since the returned `TList<IInterfaceA>` is not owned by anyone, the caller will have to manually `Free` it when done using it.  That is not the case in the original code if the `Manager` owns the list that `Find()` returns.  If it doesn't, then your original code suffers from this problem to begin with.
2. memory management of the object in the list.  Since the objects are reference counted due to `TInterfacedObject`, their reference counts will be incremented when their `IInterfaceA` interfaces are added to the returned `TList<IInterfaceA>`, and then decremented when they are removed from the list.  Since the original list returned by `Manager.Find()` contains `TClassA` object pointers and not `IInterfaceA` interface pointers, the object's reference counts will not be managed correctly.  When the `TList<IInterfaceA>` is freed/cleared, your objects are likely to get freed prematurely (unless you manually increment their reference counts when you add the `TClassA` pointers to the `Manager`'s list, and manually decrement them when removing the pointers).

Otherwise, you would need to change `Manager.Find()` to return a `TList<IInterfaceA>` instead of a `TObjectList<TClassB>`.

You should probably consider rethinking your `Manager` design anyway.  It is bad design to mix object pointers and interface pointers for interfaced objects.  When dealing with interfaced objects, you should be using interfaces for everything.  Otherwise, to avoid problems, your implementation classes need to override the `_AddRef()` and `_Release()` methods to disable reference counting.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can't "disable reference counting" because `_AddRef()` and `_Release()` will still be called, even if your implementations don't do anything. So you'd still need to take care not to destroy the underlying instance via an object reference while any interface references still point to it. I consider it safer to to manually perform additional `_AddRef()` and `_Release()` calls for each object reference pointing to the underlying instance. (Either way it's like mixing oil and water.)

Comment: @Craig: Why manually call them? Just ensure the reference is nil.

Comment: @Rudy Just to be clear we're on the same page... Remy was describing precautions to take if you ***are mixing*** object and interface references right? In which case you have an object reference that **is not nil** Setting/nilling object references _does not automatically_ call `AddRef()/Release()` (doing so for interface references ***will***). Two scenario would be undesirable: (1) Destroying object via object ref while interface refs still exist. (2) nilling all interfaces ref's and destroying object while object refs still exist. ... Easy solution: manually update refcount for objects refs

Comment: @Craig: I meant nilling the interface references, of course. Then the `_Release` call inserted by the compiler at the end of the scope will simply see a nil and all is well.

Comment: If you simply assign `nil` directly to an interface reference, its reference count will get decremented, destroying the object if it falls to 0. To nil an interface reference without decrementing the reference count, you have to cast the interface reference to a raw `Pointer` first. But that does not really solve the issue at hand, since the interface reference in question is in a `TList<T>`, so you can't nil it as a raw Pointer (well, you might be able to with some lower-level hackery).

Comment: @Remy: I agree that the Manager should manage interfaces, not objects.

Comment: @Rudy Yes do normal nilling and assignment on interface references. Manual ref counting only on object references. If you nil an interface ref where the underlying object has already been destroyed, the interface ref doesn't know the object is gone. So it still attempts `_Release` and might AV. My suggestion means that provided your manual refcounting of object refs is correct, whichever reference is `Release`d (either manually or automatically) ***last*** will result in object destruction.

Comment: @Craig: ISTM that code that does manual reference counting on an object smells pretty badly. Don't do it. Simply ensure that you don't mix object and interface references. Or, if you must, simply don't call Free.

Comment: As an aside you don't need to manually count every single object ref. You could for example just count an "owner" reference. Then your memory management is similar to normal object paradigms where you have to be sure some dangling object references wouldn't accidentally try use an object after the owner has destroyed it. (The important thing though is if the last interface ref could be nilled before all object refs are done with the instance; you don't want the object to be destroyed - holding a manual counted ref resolves that.

Comment: @Rudy ***Of course*** I agree whole-heartedly. Which is why you shouldn't mix. My advice is based on ***if you are*** mixing in spite of our advice not to.

Comment: Another side note: There is another way you can do your manual ref counting (i.e. without calling `_AddRef` and `_Release`). Add a "congenital" interface ref linked to your object ref. When you assign the object ref you also assign the interface ref. When you're done with the object ref, set your interface ref to nil. (Note, in all cases of manual ref counting, you don't want to `Free` or `Destroy` objects directly. You want to do so via `_Release`ing a reference which allows the object to self-destruct if nothing is referencing it.

Comment: @Remy PS: Simply not calling `Free` is insufficient. You also need to be sure you're not calling other methods via your object ref after the interface refs have resulted in its destruction.

Comment: @craig: if you are calling a method on the interface, there is at least one reference to it.

Comment: Looks like OP is using an ORM, and I don't know of any that can persist interfaces.